# Integration of unknown function, where $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: calculus, integration

Given that $f\in C(\mathbb{R})$, $f(5) = 2$ and $f(2)  = -2$, evaluate the following integral 
$$
\int_{2}^5 \frac{f'(x) \sin(f(x))}{1 + f^2(x)}\mathrm{d}x.
$$

I would guess that I should use integration by parts, where 
$$v'(x)=\frac{f'(x) }{1 + f^2(x)}$$ and 
$$u(x) = \sin(f(x))\,,$$
but it gets me nowhere as I have an integral of $\arctan$ times $\cos$ that I don't know how to solve.

Comment: Change of variable: $y=f(x)$. The integral reduces to $\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{\sin(y)}{1+y^2}=\int_{0}^{2}\frac{\sin(y)}{1+y^2}+\int_{-2}^{0}\frac{\sin(y)}{1+y^2}=\int_{0}^{2}\frac{\sin(y)}{1+y^2}-\int_{0}^{2}\frac{\sin(y)}{1+y^2}=0$

Comment: @Peyton: Why not add an answer?

Comment: @Peyton - Thanks!

Comment: When you see a function of $f(x)$ and a factor of $f'(x)$ out the front, that's substitution pay dirt!

Comment: You must at least assume that $f'$ exists (i.e. not only $f\in C(\mathbb R)$) to make this problem wellposed.

Answer (score 0):

Put $f(x)=t$ so your integral becomes $$\int_{-2}^2\frac{\sin t}{1+t^2}dt$$ Making $$F(t)=\frac{\sin t}{1+t^2}\text{ you can see that}\space F(t)=-F(-t)$$ therefore you have for all $t_0$ $$\int_{-t_0}^{t_0}F(t)dt=0$$ Thus the integral is equal to $0$ for the particular case $t_0=2$ (which corresponds to $f(2)=-2$ and $f(5)=2$ and have been put as values for the new definite integral above).